# copy element from one node to another using xsl

Tags: php, xml, xslt, openxml

I am using xsl to make value  at node B refere to value at node A. So, I define a key to take value `2`. then, I pass in value to w:c with `<xsl:copy-of select="key('title','w:t')"/>` Output not passing value to <w:c> </w:c>. How to copy value 2 from `<w:t>2</w:t>` to `<w:c>2</w:c>`?  Another question is, how to avoid `xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"` added to `w:c`

Content3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
  <w:t>2</w:t>
  <w:c></w:c>
</w:document>
```

format3.xls

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
     <xsl:key name="title" match="w:document" use="w:t"/>
     <xsl:template match="w:c"> 
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="key('title','w:t')"/>
                </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

index.php

```
<?php
// Load the XML source
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('content3.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('format3.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

//echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
$newDOM = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);
$newDOM->formatOutput = true;
$newDOM->save("newfile.xml")
?>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

2

<w:c xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"/>
```

Expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
    <w:t>2</w:t>
    <w:c>2</w:c>
</w:document>
```

Have try using`xsl:value-of select=` to refer value 2.

format.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
 <w:t>2</w:t>
 <w:c><xsl:value-of select="w:document/w:t"/></w:c>
</w:document>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output only display 2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add `<xsl:template match="/">` and using `xsl:value-of select="w:document/w:t"`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
   <w:t>2</w:t>
   <w:c><xsl:value-of select="w:document/w:t"/></w:c>
  </w:document>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this can generate desire output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
  <w:t>2</w:t>
  <w:c>2</w:c>
</w:document>
```